# Checking if a specific date archive is being displayed

Tags: archives, template-tags

The `is_month()`, `is_year()` or `is_week` functions don't accept arguments. Are there any other functions available that I'm able to use to determine if I'm viewing specific month/year/week archive ? Or do I have to go trough WP globals to find the current month/year/week?